# Scp: permission denied when trying to copy file from server to local device

Tags: scp

I'm running `$ scp user@domain.tld:/path/to/file .`

The file's not in the server's home directory. I ran `sudo chmod a+r` on the server's file and `sudo chmod a+w` on my local directory, but nothing changed.

Comment: You need to check the permissions for the file and its containing directories.

Comment: It was just a text file, but I changed permissions, nothing worked, and then someone on another forum suggested `$ ssh user@domain.tld -- sudo -S cat "file" > newname.txt` which worked.

Comment: OK, so you do have a permissions problem.

Comment: Yes, but I'd rather not mess with permissions of files that aren't in my home folder, for security reasons, especially on a server and when I didn't keep track of the original permission schemes.

Comment: Haha, but using `sudo` to bypass all your security?

Comment: Yes, for that moment, instead of not remembering the previous permissions schemes and risking not reverting them properly.

Comment: But to be fair, I wouldn't mind knowing what permissions I would've needed to give, exactly, e.g. `$ sudo chmod a+r` or what.

Comment: Well, you need to go back to my very first comment.

Comment: I thought that in that comment you were implying that I needed to check them so I'd know what changes to make, but I don't know what changes I would've needed to make, assuming that the changes I tried were the right ones, which it seems they weren't.

Comment: You could post what you find, so that others can take a look and give advice.